# Two priority queues for same pointers in c++

Tags: c++, stl, stl-algorithm

I have class:

```
class A{
    //fields, methods
;
```

I need an efficient data structure that allows you to choose from a variety of pointers to objects of class A minima and maxima (it should work online, that is the choice of questions will alternate with requests for adding  new poiters). This can be done by using two priority queues:

```
priority_queue<A*, vector<A*>, ComparatorForFindingLightestObjects>* qL;
priority_queue<A*, vector<A*>,  ComparatorForFindingHardestObjects>* qH;
```

The problem is that if the object pointer is extracted from the first queue, then after a while the object is destroyed, but since a pointer to the object is still present in another queue there happens errors of reading data from the freed memory.

How solve this problem by means of the standard STL containers without writing own data structures?

Comment: Consider [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: The obvious way is to use `std::shared_ptr`, but it is not optimal. Optimally you make sure the objects live longer than the queues, how to do that depends on the rest of the code.

Comment: I have found that to be a common problem, and I am nearly certain `std::priority_queue` is not compatible with any good mechanism for dealing with that problem.  So I always use my own priority queue.  If you want to use STL containers, you won't get away with having pointers directly to same unstable objects.  Either change the design to stabilize the objects or create separate intermediate objects.

Comment: perhaps use std::map instead? it can track both: minima and maxima via begin and rbegin, and complexity is similar.

Comment: @mariusm I was assuming "Lightest" is not the opposite of "Hardest" so they would not be simply two ends of a `map`  (minimize one criteria vs maximize a contending, but not strictly opposite, criteria).

Comment: std::weak_ptr can be an option for lazy cleanup

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `std::set` and delete the entry from the second set as soon as you extract the data from the first. Performance wise, both give *O(log(n))* lookup and insertion. I'm not sure if this is what you want but i'll try

```
//Use std::set as your priority queue instead
set<A*, ComparatorForFindingLightestObjects> qL; 
set<A*, ComparatorForFindingHardestObjects> qH;
auto it=qL.begin(); //The first element
if(it!=aL.end())
{
    A* curr=*it;
    qL.erase(curr); //Delete it from this
    qH.erase(curr); //Delete this from the other queue as well
}
```

Also, I think you can merge your two queues or whatever and just maintain one container. You can access the minimum  and maximum elements by `*containerName.begin()` and `*containerName.rbegin()` respectively

Comment: Instead of `*containerName.begin()` I'd prefer `containerName.front()` and `*containerName.rbegin()` should be `containerName.back()`, but they do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for `boost::multi_index` which is a single container accessible but multiple different "views": http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html